# How to current Linux process count (compared to pid_max)

Tags: linux, process, limits

How can I get the number of Linux processes (including lightweight processes)?

I want to see how many before I hit the limit dictated by `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you search for something like

`ps -elfT | wc -l`

You use the `ps` command to show all processes with threads (Light Weight Processes). The `-T` command do this for you. You should check the man page of `ps` to look around which arguments are useful for you.

The `wc -l` command will count the printed lines of the `ps` command.

Every process and every thread get a own line with the command `ps -elfT`.